# insert time into Mysql with java

Tags: java, mysql, sql, time

I`m building a database for different clients, they have their usernames and passwords, but i want to see the time when they log in. Im using following code:

```
if (userName.equals("EXAMPLE")) {


                        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                        cal.getTime();
                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
                        String Time = "update `clients` set `time`=
                          "+ sdf.format(cal.getTime()) + " where clientid=1 ";
```

But something is wrong with it and it doesn`t update table.
I would really appreciate your help.
                            Plus, as an extra question it would be nice if you could help me to update not only time but date as well.
THANK YOU Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i came up with the answer.

```
public static final String DATE_FORMAT_NOW = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss";

public static String now() {
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT_NOW);
    return sdf.format(cal.getTime());
           }
```

and then calling now() when necessery:

```
if (userName.equals("EXAMPLE")) {


                        //update time when client logged in
                        String Time = "update `clients` set `time`='" + now() + "' where clientid=1 "; 
                        stmt.executeUpdate(Time);

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a prepared statement with the parameters. That way you don't have to format the date. Can save the whole date and time.

Take a look at this link http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html.

Also it's hard to say why it's not updating since you haven't posted any code where the database update happens.

Answer (score 0):

you simply lack single quotes around the value

```
String Time = "update `clients` set `time`=
                      '" + sdf.format(cal.getTime()) + "' where clientid=1 ";
```

but keep in mind that this vulnerable with `SQL Injection`, parameterized the query by using `PreparedStatements`

- [PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html)

ex

```
String Time = "update `clients` set `time`= ? where clientid=1 ";
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStatement(Time);
pstmt.setDate(1, cal.getTime());
pstmt.executeUpdate();
```